# I have a table that is based on two foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table that is based on two foreign keys. One is `memberID`, and the second is `movieID`. I need to take from this table the row that connects these two and get from the same row `RentDays`, which is an `int`.

i did this but i think its not good:

```
public int  GetRentDays(int memberID, string movieID)
{      
    var movieRentDays = 
        from Rents in videoLibDB.Rents
        where Rents.MemberID == memberID && Rents.MovieID == movieID
        select Rents.RentDays;
        return  movieRentDays ;
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work, but you can consider JOIN construction

```
var movieRentDays= from Rents in videoLibDB.Rents
                       join member in memberTable
                           on Rents.MemberID equals memberTable.memberID
                       join movie in movieTable
                           on Rents.MemberID equals movieTable.movieID
                   select Rents.RentDays;

var singleRentDay = movieRentDays.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: public int? GetRentDays(int memberID, string movieID)
        {
            return  (from Rents in videoLibDB.Rents  where Rents.MemberID == memberID && Rents.MovieID == movieID  select Rents.RentDays).FirstOrDefault();  
        }     ////is this ok ???

Comment: Your code is OK, but I think better practise is use JOIN to connect table in DB, WHERE is better to filter condition

Comment: one more thing : if i want to update the rent movies by sending the int ' what will the query look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting an `IEnumerable<int>`, and returning the same variable, even though your method signature says you are returning an `int`. If you want to return just one `int`, and you are expecting just one from the LINQ statement, you can do something like this:

```
return
    (from Rents in videoLibDB.Rents
    where Rents.MemberID == memberID && Rents.MovieID == movieID
    select Rents.RentDays).FirstOrDefault();
```

See [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx),  [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx), and [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx).

Comment: public int? GetRentDays(int memberID, string movieID)
        {

            return
            (from Rents in videoLibDB.Rents
             where Rents.MemberID == memberID && Rents.MovieID == movieID
            select Rents.RentDays).FirstOrDefault();  
  
        }

Comment: Yes, if Rents.RentDays is a nullable int field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int GetRentDays(int memberID, string movieID)
{      
    var movieRentDays = videoLibDB.Rents.FirstOrDefault
        (r => r.MemberID == memberID && r.MovieID == movieID);
    return movieRentDays == null || movieRentDays.HasValue ? 0 
        : movieRentDays.RentDays.Value;
}
```

Comment: for some reason it wont accept only like this :    public int? GetRentDays ....       ///is ok ?    the visual studio wants me to put a "?" after the int

Comment: and another thing : how do i set rent days there ? i mean the opposite way to update a rent days

Comment: ahh, `RentDays` is an `int?` it seems. I'll revise.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a separate question, would make this post a lot more useful to other members.